# passing multiple *arg(or **kwargs) to an object by explicitly calling their name

Tags: python

This question came up to me when I was learning *arg and **kwargs in Python. Taking this example:

```
class Person1():
    def __init__(self, name, age, *petdogs):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.petdogs = list(petdogs)

    def show_dogs(self):
        for petdog in self.petdogs:
            print(petdog)
```

```
Dummy = Person1("Dummy", 16, "A", "B", "C")
Dummy.show_dogs()
#Output:
#A
#B
#C
```

**Is it possible to pass multiple * and ** arguments into an object?**

Here is what I tried:

```
class Person2():
    def __init__(self, name, age, *petdogs, *petcats):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.petdogs = list(petdogs)
        self.petcats = list(petcats)
    def show_dogs(self):
        for petdog in self.petdogs:
            print(petdog)
    def show_cats(self):
        for petcat in self.petcats:
            print(petcats)
```

then

```
Dummy2 = Person2(name = "Dummy", age = 16, petdogs = ("A", "B", "C"), petcats = ("D", "E"))
print("pet dogs:")
Dummy2.show_dogs()
print("pet cats:")
Dummy2.show_cats()
```

I want to see the out puts to be like the example above

```
pet dogs:
A
B
C
pet cats:
D
E
```

Of course it is not working, but I am wondering if there is a way to achieve by using * ?

Comment: In your case, just remove the `*` from the parameters.  You only need `*` when you want Python to package multiple arguments together into a `tuple`, but in your case you've already created the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*args` construct acts in a function as a placeholder for the rest of the arguments passed, so you can't have two 'placeholder for the rest of the arguments', because technically there's only one 'rest of arguments'.
*Example:*

```py
def f(a, b, *args):
    print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}, rest = {args}')

f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) # => a = 1, b = 2, rest = (3, 4, 5, 6)
```

`**kwargs` is similar in the spirit, but applies to arguments passed in the `keyword=value` fashion: the rest of any keyword-arguments passed are going to be displayed inside the function in the form of a `dict` of the name `kwargs`.
*Example:*

```py
def f(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}, rest = {args}, rest-kw = {kwargs}')

f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, d=7, e=8) #=> a = 1, b = 2, rest = (3, 4, 5, 6), rest-kw = {'d': 7, 'e': 8}
```

With what you want to do, there technically no 'rest' you want to express, so you can go with:

```py
class Person2():
    def __init__(self, name, age, petdogs, petcats):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.petdogs = list(petdogs)
        self.petcats = list(petcats)
    def show_dogs(self):
        for petdog in self.petdogs:
            print(petdog)
    def show_cats(self):
        for petcat in self.petcats:
            print(petcats)
```

and

```py
Dummy2 = Person2(name = "Dummy", age = 16, petdogs = ("A", "B", "C"), petcats = ("D", "E"))
print("pet dogs:")
Dummy2.show_dogs()
print("pet cats:")
Dummy2.show_cats()
```

will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that * or ** are representing "rest arguments". I thought it is just a way to pass multiple variables.